# Custom Attribute for quote table is not saving value

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

i am trying to add custom_attribute to quote table name as is_requested. this work fine, column is created. here is Upgrade schem

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('quote'),
                'is_requested',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => 0,
                    'comment' => 'Requested Quote'
                ]
            );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

now the problem is when i try to add value by this code

```
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote;

$quote = $this->quote->create();
$quote->setCustomAttribute('is_requested', '1')->save();
```

value is not save in quote table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected $quote;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quote = $quoteFactory;
    ....
}


$quote = $this->quote->create();

$quote->setData('is_requested', '1');

$quote->save();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
 */
protected $quoteRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}

public function updateQuoteData($quoteId, int $customData)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId); // Get quote by id
    $quote->setData('custom_column', $customData); // Fill data
    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote); // Save quote
}
```

Comment: thank you repository is better way to do things. but i use factory cause i want to create new object.